# Preloading Strategy issue for forChild routes

Tags: angular7, angular7-router

My application is a bit large in size. It contains many feature modules and most are lazily loaded. I want to *preload* a lazily loaded module, which is included in **forChild** routes.

For this, I have referred to Angular documentation and followed their steps. I have provided a custom preloading strategy service mentioned below.

This is my custom preloading strategy file:

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomPreloadingWithDelayStrategy implements PreloadingStrategy {
  preload(route: Route, load: () => Observable<any>): Observable<any> {
    if (route.data && route.data['preload']) {
      return load();
    } else {
      return Observable.of(null);
    }
  }
}
```

app-routing file,

```
const routes: Routes =
  [
    XXX,
{
      path: '',
      data: {
        base: true
      },
      component: MyComp,
      children: [
        {
          path: 'page1/:id',
          loadChildren: 'XXXXXXX'
        },
        {
          path: 'page2',
          loadChildren: 'XXXXXXXX'
        },        
        {
          path: 'page3',
          loadChildren: 'app/feature-modules/folder1/my-folder1-module#Folder1Module'
        }];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true,  preloadingStrategy: CustomPreloadingWithDelayStrategy})],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  entryComponents: [  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

My Folder1Module's routing file:

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: 'sub-page1/:data1/:data2',
  loadChildren: 'app/feature-modules/sub-pages/pages/sub-page1.module#SubPage1Module'
}, {
  path: 'sub-page2/:data1',
  loadChildren: 'app/feature-modules/sub-pages/pages/sub-page2.module#SubPage2Module',
  data: {preload: true}
}];


@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class Folder1RoutingModule {
}
```

So when I open this route **/page3/sub-page1/data1/data2**, *SubPage2Module* is to be preloaded. But that is not happening.

Answer (score 2):

I have spent nearly 2 hours to understand why the module is not pre-loaded even when I was doing everything right.

The problem lies with `children`, any route that is defined and further distributed with `children` is considered as a normal route even if you've defined your modules within the `children` with the help of `loadChildren`. The `preloadingStrategy` just takes modules to preload and not path/routes. The moment you've defined your routes under children it considers it as normal route and moves on to scan other routes that are provided with `loadChildren`. Following is the interpretation of Angular with your routes:

```
const routes: Routes =
[
    XXX, // Normal path
    {
        path: '',
        data: {
            base: true
        },
        component: MyComp,
        children: [    // Normal path (no module) as children is used, move on
            {
                path: 'page1/:id',
                loadChildren: 'XXXXXXX'
            },
            {
                path: 'page2',
                loadChildren: 'XXXXXXXX'
            },
            {
                path: 'page3',
                loadChildren: 'app/feature-modules/folder1/my-folder1-module#Folder1Module'
            },
        ],
    },
    { path: 'abc', loadChildren: '../path/to/module#AbcModule', data: { preload: true }}    // Module found, preload it! 
];
```

If you debug closely in your custom `CustomPreloadingWithDelayStrategy` then you will observe that your route **/page3/sub-page1/data1/data2** can't even make up to the `route` parameter of `preload()` method because preloading is all about loading module and not about loading routes. However, our route **abc** does make an appearance! Hope it helps :)